# Longest Common Suffix Is Producing Garbage Values

Tags: c, string

I'm having trouble writing a program that gets two words and finds the longest common suffix. Whenever I try to copy the contents from the words into my new string "suffix" I keep getting garbage values and I am struggling to find out where I went wrong. Any and all feedback is appreciated!

```
void longest_suffix(char word1[], char word2[]){
    char suffix[20];
    int count = 0;

    int end = strlen(word2) - 1;

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = strlen(word1)- 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(word1[i] == word2[end - j]){
            count++;
        }
        j++;
    }


    int z = 0, k = 0;
    for(k = 0; k < count; k++){
        suffix[k] == word2[end - count + z];
        z++;
    }
    suffix[k] = '\0';
    printf("%s", suffix);
}
```

Comment: `suffix[k] == word2[end - count + z];` -> `suffix[k] = word2[end - count + z];`

Comment: Also, not sure why you need `z`. Just use `k`. Other problems:  should check `count` to ensure it won't overflow your fixed size `suffix` array. and should check that `word2` is at least as long as `word2` otherwise the current code will underflow `word2`.

Comment: You should be able to break the first loop as soon as the characters don't match.  Your indexing in that loop is puzzling.  I think I'd have `int len1 = strlen(word1); int len2 = strlen(word2); int minlen = MIN(len1, len2); int i; for (i = 1; i <= minlen; i++) { if (word1[len1 - i] != word2[len2 - i]) break; } printf("%s\n", &word1[len1 - i + 1]);` give or take off-by-one boundary errors.  The variable `i` must be defined outside the loop control.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this slightly differently.
There is no need to copy the string. If there's a common suffix it's already present in `word1` and `word2` and it's already null-terminated.

```
void longest_suffix(char word1[], char word2[]){
    char *p1 = word1 + strlen(word1) - 1;
    char *p2 = word2 + strlen(word2) - 1;
    char *suffix = NULL;

    while (p1 >= word1 && p2 >= word2) {
        if (*p1 == *p2) {
            suffix = p1;
        }
        p1--;
        p2--;
    }

    printf("suffix: %s\n", suffix);
}
```

But also: this function signature is not great. And you're printing from a function that is not obviously going to print the output rather than return the results. Consider:

```
const char *longest_suffix(const char *word1, const char *word2) {
    const char *p1 = word1 + strlen(word1) - 1;
    const char *p2 = word2 + strlen(word2) - 1;
    const char *suffix = NULL;

    while (p1 >= word1 && p2 >= word2) {
        if (*p1 == *p2) {
            suffix = p1;
        }
        p1--;
        p2--;
    }

    return suffix;
}
```

I would not print or allocate from such a function. If the caller wants a copy, they can call `strdup` on the result (if it's non-NULL).

Comment: That's very similar to some code I wrote, but you run the risk of decrementing the pointers before the start of the array.  That may cause problems.  You don't try to access the memory, but in theory, you could run into problems just creating the pointer.  Forming the address one after the end of an array is guaranteed to be OK; forming the address one before the start of an array is not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

static void longest_suffix(const char word1[], const char word2[])
{
    int len1 = strlen(word1);
    int len2 = strlen(word2);
    int minlen = MIN(len1, len2);
    int i;
    assert(word1[len1] == word2[len2] && word1[len1] == '\0');
    for (i = 1; i <= minlen; i++)
    {
        if (word1[len1 - i] != word2[len2 - i])
            break;
    }
    printf("[%s] = ", &word1[len1 - i + 1]);
    printf("[%s]: ", &word2[len2 - i + 1]);
    printf("[%s] vs [%s]\n", word1, word2);
    assert(strcmp(&word1[len1 - i + 1], &word2[len2 - i + 1]) == 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    longest_suffix("abc.c", "def.c");
    longest_suffix("basename.c", "dirname.c");
    longest_suffix("spooky spells - abracadabra", "abracadabra");
    longest_suffix("abracadabra", "spooky spells - abracadabra");
    longest_suffix("xyz", "xyz");
    longest_suffix("c", "c");
    return 0;
}
```

On the whole, it would be better to separate determining the longest suffix from printing it.  Indeed, you should very often separate I/O from the calculations.  It makes it easier to reuse the calculation when the I/O requirements change.

Output:

```
[.c] = [.c]: [abc.c] vs [def.c]
[name.c] = [name.c]: [basename.c] vs [dirname.c]
[abracadabra] = [abracadabra]: [spooky spells - abracadabra] vs [abracadabra]
[abracadabra] = [abracadabra]: [abracadabra] vs [spooky spells - abracadabra]
[xyz] = [xyz]: [xyz] vs [xyz]
[c] = [c]: [c] vs [c]
```